# Flask Python String Not Returning Back To Javascript XMLHttpRequest call

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest, flask, uwsgi

I have a Javacscript XMLHttpRequest call which calls python app.py(using flask). The python script myapp.py returns "Hello World". I see in Chromium Debug that is is returning "hello world". But it's not being return to the Javascript XMLHttpRequest in the responsetext value.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function foo() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", "/myapp/web.py", true);
    xml.send(null);
    var text = xml.responseText;
    alert(text);

}
```

Here is the python script:

```
flask python # cat myapp.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return "hello world"

#@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback function to get the data due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

```
function ajaxSuccess () {
    alert(this.responseText);
}

function foo() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", "/myapp/web.py", true);
    xml.send(null);
    xml.onload = ajaxSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try  :

```
function foo() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.onreadystatechange() {
        var text = xml.responseText;
        alert(text);
    }
    xml.open("GET", "/myapp/web.py", true);
    xml.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have been solve this problem.
A way to solve this problem is that you should check the xml.readyState==4 && xml.status == 200